# Electron Typescript Document.body === null

Tags: typescript, canvas, electron

Having a little trouble with something that should be fine in vanilla js, but doesn't seem to be working as expected. I'm trying to assign `document.body` to a variable, then insert HTML into it through the `.innerHTML()` but I get an error stating that we cannot set the property of null.

Here is the code that is supposed to add the canvas to the HTML document.

```
 private createDisplay(){
    document.title = title;
    let body= <HTMLElement>(document.getElementById('container'));
    console.log(body);
    body.innerHTML = `<canvas id='canvas' width='${width}' height='${height}'</canvas>`;
    let ctx = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('canvas');
    graphics = ctx.getContext('2d');
  }
```

which started as just

```
private createDisplay(){
  document.title = title;
  let body = document.body;
  body.innerHTML = `<canvas id='canvas' width='${width}' height='${height}'></canvas>`;
.....
```

Comment: Are you running the code on the main or renderer process ?

Comment: hmm I'm running it in the renderer. I should probably do that from Main for electron, but I would be afraid to lose the option to make the canvas a dynamic size.

Comment: You should be doing everything from the renderer. How do you know the DOM has loaded? Try waiting for the `DOMContentLoaded` event before trying to access the DOM